Would there be any interest in 看图写话 (look at an image, and write about it) questions?
I'm mulling over the possibility of asking 看图写话 questions like:

看图写话
Welcome to this week's 看图写话.  Please use answers to write about the following image in Chinese:


Image source: Binyamina train station, Israel.

What should I write about?  You could literally describe what's in the image, make up a back story related to the image, tell a story from your own life related to the image, or use some other style entirely.
The aim is to practice writing, compare answers to one another and perhaps identify better phrasing or word choice, and maybe get some feedback in the comments.  It's not a competition: there's no winner nor "accepted answer".  Perhaps this could lead to questions (e.g. "I wrote [...] but another user wrote [...]; which word choice is more natural?").

The images could come from Wikimedia Commons, generative AI, Reddit, or maybe we could take our own photos or make our own drawings.  We'd need to cite the source.  It seems reasonable to make such questions/answers community wiki.
I recall seeing a puzzle style used at other sites where "this week's question" is determined by the most upvoted answer to a meta post.  It's like translation golf at Spanish.SE.
Question: Would there be any interest in 看图写话 (look at an image, and write about it) questions?

Looks like a good practice for learners :-)
